# How do I put the transfer function I get from PID tuner in Matlab in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, function, simulink, transfer

I used the PID tuner to get a transfer function from real data.

I got this:
Plant1 =
Process model with transfer function:
                        Kp
  G(s) = -------------------------------- * exp(-Td*s)/
         (1+2*Zeta*Tw*s+(Tw*s)^2)(1+Tp3*s)

```
     Kp = 50.717                                  
     Tw = 4.3132                                  
   Zeta = 0.63476                                 
    Tp3 = 0.10473                                 
     Td = 2.521
```

How do I directly put this into the simulink transferfunction?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the `Transfer Function` block is only for linear time invariant models without time delay.

You need to split your transfer function into two parts.

The time delay part `exp(-Tds)` is implemented using a [Transport Delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transportdelay.html), where your delay is `Td`.  Note that this gets approximated during simulation (with an accuracy depending on the buffer size of the block) so you won't get exactly `2.521` seconds.

The remaining part of your model is then LTI and as such can be implemented trivially using either one or two [Transfer Fcn](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/transferfcn.html) blocks.  (One if you multiply out the numerator terms; two if you want to keep them separate.)

Comment: You should define MATLAB variables, as it appears you have done, and use those variables as parameters in the appropriate Simulink blocks.

Comment: Thank you Phil. It's a shamed that it is not so simply